# Binding to an ObservableCollection<string>

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to do something very simple : I want to display an ObservableCollection in an ItemsControl. I also want the user to be able to edit the strings in the ObservableCollection.

My viewmodel is pretty straightforward :

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Values { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Values = new ObservableCollection<string> { "foo", "bar" };
    }
}
```

In my view, I define a DataTemplate for my ItemsControl to display a textbox inside each item, no problem here :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Everything seems to work smoothly, I can see the content of my ObservableCollection in my view. However, when I edit the text in the textbox, my ObservableCollection is not updated, the values are still the same.

The only workaround I've found to make this work is to create a class :

```
public class StringWrapper
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then I change the type of my ObservableCollection to `ObservableCollection<StringWrapper>`, and in my DataTemplate, I bind the Text property of my TextBox to Value. It works, but it's ugly.

So my question is, is there a way to bind an ObservableCollection to an ItemsControl and be able to update the values ?

Comment: `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />` String does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Replace it with `<TextBox Text="{Binding}" />`

Comment: @Aron : why are you answering in a comment ? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except if it's handled directly by the list control, I doubt there's any way to do that. The templated item in your `ItemsControl` only have access to the `string` instance, not to the actual collection. And since `string` is immutable, it's a dead end, there is no way to trace back the changes to the parent.

Comment: I didn't know `string` was immutable in C#. Now I understand better why it's a good pratice to use `StringBuilder`instead of directly modifying a `string`. I'll stick to the ugly way then, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

your property Values need to be implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface, after only binding with Values property will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think Binding to itself will do the work + dont forget to put it twoway.

TextBox Text="{Binding}",Mode=TwoWay

Comment: Twoway mode is the default.